# use case for LUIS (Microsoft Cognitive Service)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

we want to use LUIS to get the entities and intent from a user question and identify the entities that belong to our domain, so what we're doing is training LUIS with a lot of entities that comes from our context domain. Is this a valid and "correct" use of LUIS?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, sounds like it. You would get better answers if you provide an example of what your inputs and desired outputs look like.

Comment: I'm creating a search engine to find in medical documents with a very specific terms. For this I'm training LUIS with this kind of words or tags as "entities". But this approach implies a big bulk of terms in LUIS and I'm not sure if it's the right way to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried QnA Maker if you are returning information from docs?

Comment: no.. it's maybe an option.. I'll take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm creating a search engine to find in medical documents with a very specific terms. For this I'm training LUIS with this kind of words or tags as "entities".

Yes you are right. The medical term you are referring to are suppose to be entities.

> But this approach implies a big bulk of terms in LUIS

If there is a difference only in the term i.e if your utterances are like

- search for a
- search for b

Then you can add a and b as a phrase list in LUIS, in this way you don't have to keep repeating the utterance for each term. You can check out [how to add phrase list.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-features#add-phrase-list) If you look at the 3rd point there you can see that for the name City many city values are being entered. You can do the same with the medical terms you need to search.

In this way you can get the medical terms at your server side by inspecting the entity value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can the intents and entities fro the user question with LUIS. You have to provide training examples accordingly. There are many features in LUIS to label entities which follow a specific pattern using [Patterns feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-model-intent-pattern) [(pattern.any)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern#use-a-patternany-entity-to-find-free-form-entities-in-a-pattern) and provide [phrase lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-interchangeable-phrase-list) for synonyms. You have to use them based on the scenario. Hope that helps!!