# Correct way of using Phrase list and Pattern in Microsoft LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am a very new to LUIS. I am not able to use phrase list and pattern. Since I could not find any resource (Except Microsoft document), where I can get more details about it neither I could find any reference of demo.
It would be nice if any one can explain a bit in layman language in which scenario we can use both. 
One more thing phrase list are not listing with entity while we are working on Utterance in intent creation

Comment: A phrase list is used to substitute synonyms so that model only needs to be trained using one of the synonyms. The documentation describes this here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-interchangeable-phrase-list
Instead of having to train the system using perumutations with want, require and wish, etc, you can train for one of them.
Patterns can be used when different ordering of words should result in different intents. The example at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-patterns is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I could not find any resource (Except Microsoft document), where
>   I can get more details about it neither I could find any reference of
>   demo.

You can find more examples from this StackOverFlow [answers about using Patterns feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584535/luis-can-we-use-phrases-list-for-new-values-in-the-entity-type-list/50608350#50608350) and [Phrase Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464648/use-case-for-luis-microsoft-cognitive-service/50488522#50488522) other than Microsoft documentation.

> It would be nice if any one can explain a bit in layman language in
>   which scenario we can use both.

In short Patterns are used for labeling entities which follow a specific pattern without providing more examples whereas Phrase Lists are used for providing synonyms of the utterances.

> One more thing phrase list are not listing with entity while we are
>   working on Utterance in intent creation

Please read more about [Phrase Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature) about how to use it and how it works. If you still have issues send the snapshot with more details to Luisuservoice@microsoft.com.